# Ionic 4 Refresher Not Working?

Tags: pull-to-refresh, ionic4

I'm trying to implement a pull to refresh functionality to my app, but `ion-refresher` does not seem to be functional. Could it be a bug?

Here is my HTML component:

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="logSomethingToConsole()">
                <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
                </ion-refresher-content>
        </ion-refresher>

      <ion-row justify-content-center text-center id="temp-text">
          <h1> Some Text </h1>
      </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Dose is have any error in console ?

Comment: no, no errors anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doRefresh(event) function is not called.

You have to set the property[disabled]="false" in ion-refresher component.

See: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14992

Comment: FYI, per that Github link, this `[disabled]=false` has been patched. So if ion-refresher is not working, the problem is due to something else.